# Getting a desktop background of windows machine along with the application in Mac

Tags: mac-osx

When I open a remote app in mac, I'm getting a desktop background of windows machine along with the application. I need to show only the application to the user. Is there anyway to hide the background?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .RDP file with the Mac RDP client, in the applications portion of the menu check the box that says "Start only the following Windows applications", enter the correct path and save.

Comment: Suddenly, in my MAC when i open the rdp file, its not opening the application, instead it opens the complete remote desktop. i checked for applications portions in rdp file, it point to the correct word exe file. what could have been wrong?